# Suppose $a$ is algebraic over a field $F$. Show that $a$ and $1+a^{-1}$ have the same degree over $F$.

Tags: ring-theory

Help with this excercises

Suppose $a$ is algebraic over a field $F$. Show that $a$ and $1+a^{-1}$ have the same degree over $F$.

I think that  $F(a)=F(1+a^{-1})$, which may or may not help me solve this question. I feel like there must be a simple trick that I'm simply overlooking.

I guess that,, $a\in F $ and $1\in F$ then $F(1+a^{-1})\subseteq F(a)$ or no?? how proof that $F(a) \subseteq F(1+a^{-1})$

But $a\in F $??

Comment: Your proposed idea is good! What are you confused about?

Comment: I guess that,, $a\in F $ and $1\in F$ then $F(1+a^{-1})\subseteq F(a)$ or no?? how proof that $F(a) \subseteq F(1+a^{-1})$

Comment: Well, $1 \in F$, so $(1+a^{-1}) - 1 = a^{-1} \in F(1+a^{-1})$, and certainly $F(1+a^{-1})$ is closed under inversion of nonzero elements. Also, it's not right to say that $a \in F$; you probably meant $a \in F(a)$.

Comment: But $a\in F $??

Answer (score 0):

Once you show that $F(a) = F(1 + a^{-1})$, you are essentially done, as the degree of $a$ over $F$ is the degree of the minimal polynomial of $a$ over $F[x]$, which is the same as the degree of the field extension $F(a)/F$.

Comment: But $a\in F $??

Comment: You are supposed to assume that $a \in F$. You are only assuming that $a$ is algebraic over $F$.

Comment: mm yes,, then $a^{-1} \in  F$? maybe no

Comment: No. You don't need $a$ or $a^{-1}$ to be in $F$. I think you are misunderstanding the notation $F(a)$. It does not mean that $a \in F$. It denotes a field extension of $F$ which contains $F$ and $a$. For example, $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ is the field
$$\{p + q\sqrt{2} : p,q \in \mathbb{Q}\},$$
but $\sqrt{2} \not\in \mathbb{Q}$.